# New column and iteration over rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to add a new column in my existing dataset (`pandas dataframe`). This new column contains elements that satisfy a specific condition (please see code below). I am iterating over rows, but I am not able to change value of the row based on the condition (rows should have value `row_value[0] = var2` or `row_value[0] = varB`).

```
for index, row in sample_dataset.iterrows():
            row_value = ['Missing']
            for var1, var2 in var3:
                if row[0].endswith(var1):
                    row_value[0] = var2
                    break
            for varA,varB in varC:
                if row[0].endswith(varA): 
                    row_value[0] = varB
                    break
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Example:

Original Dataset:

```
Column
hello_world.a
goodmorning_world.b
bye_world.1
...
```

Lists are:

```
var1=['1','2','3']
var2=['11','22','33']
var3=list(zip(var1, var2))
```

similarly for `varA, varB, varC`:

```
varA=['a','b','c']
varB=['aa','bb','cc']
varC=list(zip(varA, varB))
```

I would like to have something like this:

Expected output

```
Column                  New_column
hello_world.a               aa
goodmorning_world.b         bb
bye_world.1                 11
...
```

Comment: Are you new to python? Cause this code looks very confusing and filled with mistakes. For example you are defining row_value as a list containing the string 'Missing', in the question you say that you want to change the value of some of your dataframe rows, but the only thing you're changing by writing row_value[0] = var2 is row_value = ['Missing'] that you defined previously, whereas your dataframe is called sample_dataset. Explain better what the variables are (like var1,2 and 3) and give an example of your dataframe and how you would like to change it, otherwise it's hard for us to help.

Comment: Yes I am. With 'missing' I am assigning something that it is not `var2` or `varB`. I will update my post. However I think sometimes it needs just only the structure, as everything could suit fine in this case, as the logic is the problem, not the expected output (thought it is mentioned in my question: rows should have value row_value[0] = var2 or row_value[0] = varB).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, let's go step by step trough your code, first let's define the dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

# create dataframe with nans in the new column you want to fill
sample_dataset = pd.DataFrame({'Column':['hello_world.a','goodmorning_world.b','bye_world.1']})

# create new column which we will fill later 
sample_dataset['New_column'] = pd.Series(index = sample_dataset.index, dtype='object')
```

Note that it is important to specify the type of the new column because what you want to achieve is the creation of a new column with mixed element types, numbers and strings, and only python 'objects' can hold mixed types.

Let's print it to see how it looks like

```
print(sample_dataset)
Out:
                Column  New_column
0        hello_world.a         NaN
1  goodmorning_world.b         NaN
2          bye_world.1         NaN
```

Now let's move to the rest of your code:

```
# the other variables you defined 
var1=['1','2','3']
var2=['11','22','33']
var3=list(zip(var1, var2))
varA=['a','b','c']
varB=['aa','bb','cc']
varC=list(zip(varA, varB))

# your code
for index, row in sample_dataset.iterrows():
            row_value = ['Missing']
            for var1, var2 in var3:
                if row[0]. endswith(var1):
                    row_value[0] = var2
                    break
            for varA,varB in varC:
                if row[0].endswith(varA): 
                    row_value[0] = varB
                    break
```

Let's check if your code did something to the dataframe

```
Out:
                Column  New_column
0        hello_world.a         NaN
1  goodmorning_world.b         NaN
2          bye_world.1         NaN
```

Nothing seems to change, but something actually did, which is row_value. If I try to print it after running your code I get:

```
print(row_value)
Out:
['11']
```

Again, this is the most striking mistake because it shows that your issue is not just with pandas and dataframes but with programming in general. If you want to modify a variable, you have to access that variable, here the variable you want to change is your dataframe, which is called sample_dataset, but instead of calling it you call row_value in these lines:

```
row_value[0] = var2
row_value[0] = varB
```

Which is why at the end of your code row_value is not anymore ['Missing'] but ['11'], so you are changing something, just not your dataframe.

So how to update the values in the new column of the initial dataframe? Here's how you should do it:

```
# iterating through rows, this is correct
for index, row in sample_dataset.iterrows():
            
            # you don't need to define row_value, but you want to access the value of 'Column' in the current row
            value = row['Column']
            
            # you could just do "for var1, var2 in list(zip(var1, var2))" without defining var3, not a mistake but it makes the code more concise
            for var1, var2 in var3:
                
                # using .endswith() will raise an error when you try to apply it to numbers, an alternative that works for both numbers and string is to simply access the last element of the array with [-1]
                if value[-1] == var1:
                    
                    # this is how you change an element in a dataframe, i.e. using .at[index, column]
                    # here we say that we want to change the element in the current index in the column 'New_colum' with var2 
                    sample_dataset.at[index,'New_column'] = var2
                    break
                    
            for varA,varB in varC:
                
                # same story as before
                if value[-1] == varA: 
                    
                    sample_dataset.at[index,'New_column'] = varB
                    break
```

Let's print again the dataframe to check if this works:

```
print(sample_dataset)
Out:
                Column New_column
0        hello_world.a         aa
1  goodmorning_world.b         bb
2          bye_world.1         11
```

So this time we did access the dataframe and change the values of New_column successfully. Go though the code and if you have doubts just comment, I can explain it in more details.

As a final note, if what you want is to just take the last character in the first row and double it in a new column, there are much better ways to do it. For example:

```
for index, row in sample_dataset.iterrows():
            
            value = row['Column']
            
            sample_dataset.at[index, 'New_column'] = value[-1]*2
```

Again, if we print it we can see that three lines of code are enough to do the job:

```
print(sample_dataset)
Out:
                Column New_column
0        hello_world.a         aa
1  goodmorning_world.b         bb
2          bye_world.1         11
```

In this way, you don't need to define varA,B,C and all the others and you don't need brakes or nested for loops. We can even compress the code to a single line using .apply()

```
sample_dataset['New_column'] = sample_dataset.apply(lambda x: x['Column'][-1]*2, axis=1)
```

This will give you again the same results as before, but if you had trouble with your code this might be something you want to leave for the future when you will have a bit more confidence.

Also please note just that the last two methods will create all string elements, so even the last element 11 would be a string and not a float64. This might be something that you want to avoid, in which case you should just use your code, but in general it is not a really good things to mix types in a column though.

## Edit

if you want to extract a part of a string respecting a specific rule (in this case, everything after the last period) you need to use regular expressions (or regex). Regex in python are implement in the library re, what you need to do is:

```
# import library
import re

# define a patter of interest, this specific pattern means 'everything from the end of the string until you find a period'
pattern = r"([^.]*$)"

# now you can extract the final part from each element in your dataframe using re.search
last_part = re.search(pattern, element).groups()[0]
```

Just to show what it does, let's take a fake value like 'hello_world.com' and apply the regex to it:

```
print(re.search(pattern, 'hello_world.com').groups()[0])
Out:
com
```

Now, you want to change in your code value[-1] with re.search so

```
if value[-1] == var1:
if value[-1] == varB:
```

Should become

```
if re.search(pattern, value).groups()[0] == var1:
if re.search(pattern, value).groups()[0] == varB:
```

Remember to add the import for re and to define the pattern at the beginning of your code.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and for explaining it step by step. I tried with different letters at the end of the word (as what I used as example was just a sample from my list), and when I change them in the lists (for example `.a -> .it or .b-> .bh`) I get `NaN` in the result. Example: `hello_world.it -> NaN`, also after changing  `varA=['it','b','c'], varB=['Italy','bb','cc']`. Do you know why?

Comment: I think it is because I am considering only the last letter, but I would need all the parts after the dot. My fault as I have not mentioned it in my post that I need to consider all the part after . Could you please tell me how could I do without using ends string ?

Comment: I've added it to the answer

Comment: No problem. To include the point the easiest way is to simply add it to the result of re.search, so: **'.' + re.search(pattern, value).groups()[0]** instead of simply: **re.search(pattern, value).groups()[0]**. in this way you will get as a result first '.' + 'com' which then become '.com'  since python supports operations between strings.